# Instance Variables in objective C

Tags: objective-c, class, methods, instance-variables, initializing

lets say I have the following class

```
@implementation userSetUp{
    NSString *folderIdentification;
}

-(id) initWithDriveService:(GTLRDriveService *)driveService withFilePath: (NSString *)aFilePath{
 folderIdentification = some string
 }
end
```

now I have another method in the same class, but folderIdentification is returning null even though I defined it in the initializer method for the class. Could someone please tell me how I should define folderIdentification so that I can get the same instance behavior found in swift and java and the folderIdentification in reuploadToFolder does not return null?

```
-(void )reuploadToFolder{
 folderIdentification is used but for some reason is nill.
 }
```

Comment: Make sure to call super's designated initializer in the beginning of your `initWithDriveService:withFilePath:` method, and assign the result to `self`, and make sure to do this *before* you assign the instance variable (Objective-C is different from Swift in this regard). Also, make sure to return `self` at the end of the method. I can't guarantee that that's the source of your problem, but might be, since the initializer as written is incorrect.

Comment: Please post real code. The code you have posted isn't valid Objective-C code and your `init` method isn't valid.

Comment: Try this `@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *folderIdentification;`